# file path for a Cron job script in a zendframework project

Tags: zend-framework, cron

I have a zendframework project. I need to create a cronjob from the Cpanel. But I have one doubt. Where I put the cronjob script file (in public_html? or anywhere in the project as in the usual manner). Then what is the path i have to give in the Command textbox in Cpanel

Please reply anyone. I am still waiting .... Please ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can really put it wherever you like.

I typically create a directory in my project root called "cli/", and put stuff in there.

Usually I'll have a little boot.php script that looks a lot like my app's index.php, but ends with `$application->bootstrap();` instead of `$application->bootstrap()->run();`

As for your cron job, you can do something like:

```
* * * * * ENVIRONMENT=production /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/project/cli/script.php
```